# Green square on game canvas using Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

Can someone please tell me why I'm getting a green square on my Phaser game canvas as below?

[image: Green Square]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing any code I can tell you that you'll see that when an image can't be loaded by the Phaser framework.

Open developer tools in your browser of choice and refresh after opening the Network tab. You should see a 404 for one of your images.

I believe if you look at the standard browser console you may also see messages about the name of the asset that it failed to load.

Comment: Okay, I think the problem may lie with this line of code as I assume I need to setup the start position of the spaceship:         this.play = game.add.sprite(200, 245, 'play'); // Display the spaceship at the position x = 10 and y = 245. It is saying this in the console: Phaser.Cache.getImage: Key "play" not found in Cache.

Comment: Which means that you're not loading in something with the key `play`. You should have something like `game.load.image('play', 'assets/play.png');` in your preload, just as you do with your spaceship and asteroids.

Comment: Thanks for that - bit of a novice using Phaser so still learning the ropes!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with Phaser; it's quite a nice framework :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different case. Images were being loaded in the `init` function, which apparently doesn't work. I renamed that function to `preload` and suddenly the green squares are gone and the images show up.

Answer (score 0):

My case was also a little different too; it appeared that all my image resources were loaded, but I think I was trying to create the sprites a little too quickly - in order words, I was trying to create and add sprites to my scene before the scene was properly loaded.

I'm going to try waiting until 'scene.scene.isActive(key);' returns a boolean of true.....maybe that's what will solve my issue.  Failing that, I might just put in some sort of sleep/await promise of 1 second or something (not ideal, but might work)

ALSO NOTE:  Part of the reason I was able to create my sprites too quickly was because I was doing so in my own custom function, not the typical create() function.  Actually, the best solution is probably to create my sprites in the create() function and not a custom function...